# Having a problem when miltiplying DataGridView after sum

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new at coding and I'm having a bit of a problem when trying to multiply a summed value from a DataGridView.

Basically, what I want to do is to sum all the values of a DataGridView column into a textbox and then multiply it by the value from another textbox.

So far I've been able to sum all the values from de DGV buy cant seem to figure out how to multiply it with the other textbox.

My code is as follows:

```
private void BtAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DgvBuscador.DataSource != null)
    {
        this.DgvCarrito.DataSource = null;
    }
    else
    {
        this.DgvCarrito.Rows.Clear();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < DgvBuscador.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = DgvCarrito.Rows.Add();
        DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    }
    TbTotal.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in DgvCarrito.Rows
                    where row.Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                    select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
}
```

Comment: you select always "row.Cells[6].FormattedValue" and i cannot see the multiplication.... it is not clear for me what do you want to do..

Comment: i've not added the multiplication to the code yet.
what i have is a range of dates that calculates the ammount of days between them. what i want to do is to multiply that number of days to the sum of values that the row 6 gives me.

Comment: that ranges of days is calculated into a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried a different method that i've wanted and it worked.

```
            TbTotal.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in DgvCarrito.Rows
                        where row.Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                        select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].FormattedValue) * Convert.ToInt32(TbNoches.Text)).Sum().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

here's another code that works better for what i wanted. now when i add the selected row from one DGV to another DGV, the column 6 (which is the vale) gets multiplied by the number of days from the textbox that calculates the date range.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < DgvBuscador.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
        {
            int index = DgvCarrito.Rows.Add();
            DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value = DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            DgvCarrito.Rows[index].Cells[6].Value = (Convert.ToInt32(DgvBuscador.SelectedRows[i].Cells[6].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(TbNoches.Text)).ToString();
        }
        TbTotal.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in DgvCarrito.Rows
                        where row.Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                        select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
```